# Setting label's width and height according to the text length within a UITableViewCell using UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Tags: uitableview, uilabel, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I need a UITableView with cells like this:
[image]
I tried and ended up in this:
[image]

I used UITableViewAutomaticDimension with Autolayout (pinning the label to 4 sides of the superview and not giving a height constraint) and was able to give dynamic height to the cells. But what I also want is the width of the label to be adjusted according to the size of the text (see first image).

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: does your problem still exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For that all you need to add flexible constraint that adjust according to message label.**

[image]

Give **message** **label** **trailing** to Main SuperView (**ContentView**) in Greater than or equal to (**>=**) let say 20 pixels (so it's basically **means always maintain that margin of 20 pixels space** so it can go more then 20 pixels but not less then that). now you can give **trailing** of your **ChatView** to **Message label** let say 20 pixels.

also add **tailing margin** of 20 pixels as in Greater than or equal to (**>=**) Date label so when the message get very small your background view of **message label** will not go inside of date.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Govind, that was the perfect solution.